# How much resources does MySQL (MariaDB) use vs. Apache/PHP-FPM on my server?

Tags: centos, mysql, apache-2.4, php-fpm

I host about 60 client sites on this server:
AMD EPYC 7401P 24 Cores "Naples" (Zen)
128GB DDR4 ECC RAM
NVMe storage.
Centos7

All sites are PrestaShop 1.7 sites with each their own PHP 7.1 PHP-FPM pool as well as one MySQL (MariaDB) database for each site.

The speed is good, but I am considering to migrate to one separate MySQL server and one web-server.

I have NO IDEA how much resources MySQL uses vs Apache and PHP-FPM.

Let's say I keep Apache and PHP-FPM on my current server and buy a new server for MySQL. What server should I get? Half the RAM and CPU compared to the webserver? Double, same?

My guess is that the answer is: **it's hard to say without real data**, so a followup would then be: how can I get this data, preferably *resource usage over time*? Is this data hidden in the system allready or do I need to install some statistics tool?

Answer (score 0):

(I don't know about PrestaShop, I will address generic scaling with MySQL.)

Yes, moving the database to a separate server is a reasonable first-step in scaling your application.

- How much data do you have (or will you have)?  RAM size is a tradeoff between having enough to cache most or all the data versus the cost of RAM.
- CPU (for MySQL) does not matter.  Almost always, excess CPU usage can be solved by improving indexing and/or queries.
- Disk speed *may* be important.
- MySQL wants to use RAM and Disk.  Apache and PHP want to use CPU.  So you may not see much improvement.
- If you can identify that Apache/PHP/PrestaShop is the hog, you can have multiple servers running that, then have one MySQL server.
- If MySQL is the hog, let's see the slow queries.  If things can be solved, then Replication is likely to be the solution.

As for investigating/improving the current (single-server) setup:

- If the clients come and go, don't configure for a full 60 connections.
- MySQL desires 70% of *available* RAM and hates when swapping occurs.  "Available" means after accounting for OS, code, other apps.
- Windows? or Unix?  Let's see the top part of `top` when sorted by memory.  And by CPU.  (During a busy time)